# Create date object from Date picker and Time Picker

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I'm trying to create  a date object in Android from Date picker and Time picker. I know how to do seperatly but when I want to create single Date object using both Date picker and Time picker

I tried this

```
DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePickerDelayed);
TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePickerDel);
Date myDbDate = new Date(dp.getYear(), dp.getMonth(), dp.getDayOfMonth(), tp.getCurrentHour(), tp.getCurrentMinute());
```

but no luck as it is deprecated. Any one can please point me to a resource?

Comment: did you tried my code from below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use Calendar, i'm working with it

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, dayOfMonth);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```